# What is the meaning of "Visual Studio 20xx C++ Compiler"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a requirement that I should use "Visual Studio 20xx C++ Compiler",
but I don't understand what that refers to.

Is it "Visual Studio 2020" or "Visual Studio 20.0 or better" or something else?

Comment: Take it to mean "the latest edition of Visual Studio". That is 2019 as of the time of writing.

Comment: Very Thanks,I understood

Comment: Or, it could mean using Visual Studio with the option set to use the C++20 Language Standard (the `/std:c++20` command-line option). Unlikely, though.

Comment: I would say 20xx would refer to *at least* the oldest version which is Visual C++ .NET 2002 (known for its Visual C++ 7.0). But 2002-2008 are retired, as far as I know. VS 2008 implemented Visual C++ 9.0. Version VS2010, still used by some programmers because of certificate and compliance reasons, implements part of the Visual C++ 11 standard, they finished that with VS 2012. I think it is safe to assume if your code complies with Visual C++ 9.0, it will compile with any version starting with VS 2010.